# get a set of data from a chat log by using regex and java

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a Java program  where I have to extract some data from a chat log file for a further processing using regex(I am new to regular expressions by the way). The chat log schema is defined as follows:**[hh:mm:ss] string**.

But the specific lines I would like to extract data are in the form of
**[hh:mm:ss] <data1> data2**. The data I would like to extract are hh:mm:ss, data1 and data2.
At first, I have tried to extract the time which was easier using 
**Pattern.compile("(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})**. 

I have even been able to extract the data1 separately using 
 **Pattern p1=Pattern.compile("<(.*)>")**; and it was fine.

But when I try to get "hh:mm:ss",data1 and data2 by using the following regex 
**Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) <(.*)> (.*)")** I have no match found.
So does any one have an Idea on how I can proceed in that case to achieve my goal?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you were matching your own pattern everything would have been fine. You forget about the brackets of the time: **[** hh:mm:ss **]** . See here:

```
    String text = "22:44:55 <data quite much> data 2";
    text = text.replaceAll("(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}) <(.*)> (.*)", "replacement");
    System.out.println(text);
    text = "[22:44:55] <data quite much> data 2";
    text = text.replaceAll("(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}) <(.*)> (.*)", "replacement");
    System.out.println(text);
```

This produces:

```
replacement
[22:44:55] <data quite much> data 2
```

So first string was matched and second one - not. Just as expected.

Probably you will just need to change your pattern to `\\[(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\] <(.*)> (.*)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Boris, it works perfectly. I can now carry on the programming process. I owe you one